# Google Sheets API format cells PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-sheets-api

i'm importing some data with Google API from a spreadsheet file in my Google Drive through the code:

```
 $response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
 $values = $response->getValues();
```

For the values, it works well. But how can i import the format of the cells that contains that values?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

use `$service->spreadsheets->get` for response